# How to write firebase security rules like if a user post a post then only he and Admins can write to it rest user can only read it?

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

This is my firebase data structure:

[image]

Here under Posts->PIN->postsIds-> phone 123456789 , only he and Admins can write to this postsId node.

How to write such security rules ?

**My current security rule**

```
"rules": {
    "Admins": {
      ".read": "auth != null",
      ".write": "auth != null",
    },
    "All_Posts": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    },
    "Posts": {
      ".read": true,
      ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    },
    "Users": {
      ".read": "auth.uid != null",
      ".write": "auth.uid != null"
    }
  }
```

**Update Rules**
After adding custom claim like

```
const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp();

exports.sellerCustomClaim = functions.database.ref('/Users/{userNumber}')
.onCreate((data, context) => {
    const sellerNumber = context.params.userNumber;
    const uid = context.auth.uid;
    const customClaims = {
      number: sellerNumber,
    };

    console.log(`Uid: ${uid}, number: ${sellerNumber}`);

    console.log(`before Seller number: ${sellerNumber}`);
    return admin.auth().setCustomUserClaims(uid, customClaims).then(() => {
        console.log(`claim added!`);
    })
    .catch(error => {
        console.log(error);
    })
});
```

I have add admin true in the same way

```
const customClaims = {
      admin: true,
    };
```

And i have written my Posts like

```
"Posts": {
      "$pin": {
        "$pid": {
          ".read": true,
          ".write": "auth.token.admin === true || data.child('phone').val() === auth.token.phone"
        }
      }
    },
```

So that everyone can read it but only admin and if the post phone number and current user number is same.

How to do it?

Comment: I'm assuming that you tried something and got stuck on a specific step while implementing this use-case. Can you edit your question to include the [minimal security rules and corresponding code that allows any of us to reproduces where you got stuck](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)?

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen i have added my rule

Comment: Those are very basic rules, and give us very little to go on how your authentication works (as the 6 digit numbers are not UIDs from one of Firebase's built-in providers). I'd recommend reading a bit more in the documentation, reading some previous [questions on the topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/firebase-realtime-database+firebase-security-rules), searching for some tutorials, and trying to get a bit closer yourself.

Comment: Thanks i'll inform.

Comment: @FrankvanPuffelen can you help me little?

Comment: Those rules look OK at first glance. What doesn't work about it?

Comment: Ok, thanks i'll update you if any think goes wrong